# Can an external user be in more that 1 Twilio conversation with the same number?

Tags: twilio, twilio-conversations

Can  Twilio Conversations API allow an external participant to be in more than 1 conversation? For example; I have a conversation with Jane and John and a second conversation with Jane and Joe. Jane is a member of 2 conversations. If Jane sends an SMS to the Twilio number, how does the SMS route to the correct conversation?

**Edit**
My question is can the participant join multiple conversations with a single proxy number.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can have a participant in multiple conversation. The conversation api only throws if error participant is already in that conversation  Error - 50416.

For routing to correct conversation it uses proxy that is combination of participants number and the "To" number.

Comment: I'm still not clear, because if a participant is in multiple conversations, the incoming message is the same "from" number and same "to" number. Are you saying that an external participant can be in a single conversation per each proxy?

Comment: At any given time, there can only be one ongoing conversation with the same "from" and "to" numbers (proxy). If you attempt to start a new conversation with the same proxy, the conversation will be created, but you will encounter an error when you try to add a participant to the conversation (using the existing "from" and "to" numbers).

Comment: further refer this https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/user-guide#incoming-conversation